# Set font size for acmart sigconf document class

Tags: fontsize, acmart

I want to set the font size to 10pt for the [ACM article template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). But I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is. I guess it is either: `\documentclass[sigconf,fontsize=10pt]{acmart}` or `\documentclass[sigconf,10pt]{acmart}`

In the acmart.cls, they have the following code for font size:

```
\def\ACM@fontsize{}
\DeclareOptionX{9pt}{\edef\ACM@fontsize{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOptionX{10pt}{\edef\ACM@fontsize{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOptionX{11pt}{\edef\ACM@fontsize{\CurrentOption}}
\DeclareOptionX{12pt}{\edef\ACM@fontsize{\CurrentOption}}


\ifx\ACM@fontsize\@empty
  \ifcase\ACM@format@nr
  \relax % manuscript
    \def\ACM@fontsize{9pt}%
  \or % acmsmall
    \def\ACM@fontsize{10pt}%
  \or % acmlarge
    \def\ACM@fontsize{10pt}%
  \or % acmtog
    \def\ACM@fontsize{9pt}%
  \or % sigconf
    \def\ACM@fontsize{9pt}%
  \or % siggraph
    \def\ACM@fontsize{9pt}%
   \or % sigplan
    \def\ACM@fontsize{10pt}%
   \or % sigchi
    \def\ACM@fontsize{10pt}%
  \or % sigchi-a
    \def\ACM@fontsize{10pt}%
  \fi
```

Thanks for your help. I guess this is a newbie question.

Comment: With `\documentclass[sigconf,10pt]{acmart}` I get ten point size; the main font is `\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/10`. For some reasons known only to ACM, `sigconf` with `fontsize=10pt` chooses 9pt.

Answer (score 10):

The correct way is `\documentclass[sigconf,10pt]{acmart}`. This is the official answer I get from the conference chairs.